# Searching / filtering ListView by multiple criterias

Tags: java, android, listview, search

I currently have an layout with a ListView and a EditText widget.
The objects in the ListView contains departure locations and destinations.
The EditText is used for filtering the departure locations.
I would like to add another EditText widget to be able to filtering the list both by departure locations and destinations.
Any ideas how to add another filter class and filter the ListView content by the departures and then by the destinatiions?

```
public class PlacesActivity extends Activity{
private EditText SearchText;
private RelativeLayout search;
private ImageButton btnSearchClose;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.places_layout);

SearchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SearchBox);
SearchText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

btnSearchClose = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.SearchClose);
placesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PlacesListView);

}

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
}

    private final class MyFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
        ArrayList<Routes> results = new ArrayList<Routes>();
        orig = routes;  
        }

        if (constraint != null) {
            if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                for (Routes o : orig) {
                    String Constr = constraint.toString();
                    constraint = Constr.subSequence(0, Constr.length());

                    String FromRoute = o.getTripFrom().toLowerCase();
                    if (FromRoute.startsWith((String) constraint)) {
                        results.add(o);
                    }   
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
        }
        return oReturn;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        ArrayList<Routes> objects = new ArrayList<Routes>();
        objects = (ArrayList<Routes>)results.values;
        routes = objects;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write you own `BaseAdapter` which extends `Filterable`. You can look into how a `CursorAdapter` (which is a `Filterable` but doesn't support changing/adding Filters).

CursorAdapter
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter